# Is there any way where Airflow can pick my DAG files from s3 directly?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow can only pick DAGs from either "/dags" folder or in the particular Github repository.

Any other ways we can make Airflow pick DAG's from?

Comment: You can sync DAGs from s3 bucket or any file repository. How is your airflow deployed/hosted(AWS, on-prem, K8s, etc)?

Comment: Deployed on Kubernetes.

Comment: You can create a side-car container that can sync DAGs from s3 to your /dags folder. If you have the DAGs mounted to a volume then you can do the syncing externally via some cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have chance to run [mount-s3](https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3) with docker entry-point? that should mount s3 bucket as a local directory with startup. then you could point to it as dags directory.